# Why should we use encryption algorithms to protect the security of login actions?

Tags: html, encryption

Someone says using plaintext in login ajax may cause serious security problems. Attackers can wireshark and analyse in order to get some useful information. How can they realize cracking? By the way, if I use RSA in my login ajax and return "OK" or "failed" to judge whether the user can pass, should I need to encrypt the return strings such as "OK" and "failed"?

Comment: https://www.troyhunt.com/heres-why-your-static-website-needs-https/

Comment: Making decisions like this without the necessary cryptographic knowledge can be dangerous, I suggest you implement HTTPS and let years of cryptographic research and practice do the work for you.

Comment: pertinent idea, thanks @Luke Joshua Park

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no security implications that arise from using AJAX as a means to transmit login applications. It doesn't matter how you send your login data; what matters is how you process that data on the server.

Wireshark (or similar) could indeed be used to work out the packets (data) that was sent by someone on the same network. They essentially see whatever gets sent from the user to your server. If you only send plaintext, they can see plaintext.

The **best** way to prevent this is simply by getting HTTPS for your website, which will automatically encrypt the data using TLS (or possibly SSL). If you want to go to the trouble of setting up full RSA encryption instead, that will likely suffice... though I'd recommend HTTPS on top of that.

And no, you wouldn't need to encrypt the response from the server, as it's not sensitive information. You're simply returning the 'success' / 'failure' messages, which isn't sensitive information; a login either succeeds or fails.

Comment: Full RSA encryption probably wouldn't suffice unfortunately. Getting the RSA public key to the client **without** https isn't really possible, since communicating the RSA public key will be done over http and thus can be MITMed. OP should use HTTPS, and **not** try and solve this problem themselves.

Answer (score 1):

1. Users may share passwords across many platforms, if you do not encrypt the password when attempting login it may get intercepted by a third-party
2. An attacker may modify a login form action, thus stealing the users credentials

There are several other reasons for this, but if you would like to know more about login security and best practices, see [this link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet)

You do not need to encrypt the response from the server though.